# Box2D setGravity() in Andengine?

Tags: box2d, andengine

Im currently using the Andengine GLES20 branch. I know that the new Box2D method setGravity() isn't implemented yet.

Has anyone managed yet to get it to work with Andengine or to write a method which does the same? I really need this new feature of Box2D.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

get latest source : https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine

It has the method

```
mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, 0), false);
mPhysicsWorld.setGravity(pGravity);
```

where pGravity is Vector2 object for x and y values for your gravity. like Vector2(0,5).